# How can a function set the value of a variable without returning the value of that variable?

Tags: python, import, root, program-entry-point, argv

I want to import a particular and unusual module. In order to import this module, I must prepare the environment for its import, import the module, and then change the environment again following its import. The way I can do this is as follows:

```
argv_tmp = sys.argv
sys.argv = []
from ROOT import *
sys.argv = argv_tmp
```

I want to abstract the procedures surrounding the actual import into two functions resulting in main code of the following form:

```
pre_ROOT_import()
from ROOT import *
post_ROOT_import()
```

How can these functions -- functions that take no arguments and return no values -- perform these procedures?

Comment: This sounds like a very poorly planned module... Is it publicly available? If so, which one is it?

Comment: And what's stopping you from just putting those lines of codes into functions? Have you tried it and gotten an error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Use the `global` keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A context manager works well here. It holds sys.argv locally and restores it even if an exception is raised in ROOT.

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def argv_tmp():
    tmp = sys.argv
    sys.argv = []
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.argv = tmp

with argv_tmp():
    from ROOT import *
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this many times. This is a picture-perfect use case for context managers.

Comment: This could be improved by putting the `yield` into a `try: ... finally: ...` to ensure the environment is still restored if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It is clear and concise. I think that [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33487239/1556092) presented by @MikeMüller is also very good. Thanks for introducing me to context managers!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very nice use case for a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=contextmanager#typecontextmanager).

```
class ArgvContext(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.tmp_argv = sys.argv
        sys.argv = []
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.argv = sys.tmp_argv
```

Usage:

```
with ArgvContext():
    from ROOT import *
```

The code in `__enter__` is executed before and the code in `__exit__` after the context. Context here just means everything that is indented under the `with` statement. Use attributes to `self` to carry information from before to after.

A simple example:

```
class Context(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('start')
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('end')

with Context():
    print('doing')
```

prints:

```
start
doing
end
```

The code in `__exit__` is also executed in case of an exception:

```
with Context():
    1 / 0
```

Output:

```
start
end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: @skrrgwasme Was still typing ;).

Comment: Thank you very much for your extremely clear, correct and detailed answer. I hate this, but I had to go [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers) to try to find out what to do if I want to accept two answers. The highest rated answer ([this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/13397/revisions)) suggests that I upvote all correct answers and accept the answer that either I actually use or that came in first. I want to accept your answer also, but StackOverflow prevents me from doing so.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I think just pulling arg_tmp to outside of the functions should do the trick, the functions can still access it.

```
import sys
argv_tmp = None

def pre_ROOT_import():
  #set argv_tmp and modify sys.argv
def post_ROOT_import():
  #restore sys.argv to argv_tmp

pre_ROOT_import()
from ROOT import *
post_ROOT_import()
```